# JDK-18 foreign functions: How to work with multiple functions that have the same name, but come from different native libraries?

Tags: java, project-panama

Let's say I loaded a native library `gg3` that has a function `get_gg()`, and would like to load another native library `gg4` that also has a `get_gg()` function - how can I look one up in a "library aware" manner (for example, use the `get_gg()` from `gg4` on certain occasions, and otherwise from `gg3`)?

I tried `CLinker.systemCLinker().lookup()` but that seems to just fetch the first symbol that is found in the loaded native libraries.

After searching in the internal classes, I found `SystemLookup.libLookup()` which seemed promising but isn't public, so I implemented a similar method to lookup a loaded native lib:

```
private static SymbolLookup libLookup(Function<NativeLibraries, NativeLibrary> loader) {
        NativeLibrary lib = loader.apply(NativeLibraries.rawNativeLibraries(SystemLookup.class, false));
        return name -> {
            Objects.requireNonNull(name);
            try {
                long addr = lib.lookup(name);
                return addr == 0 ?
                        Optional.empty() :
                        Optional.of(NativeSymbol.ofAddress(name, MemoryAddress.ofLong(addr), ResourceScope.globalScope()));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        };
    }
```

However, this apparently is prohibited, because I cannot load the library from another class loader (and I don't know what class loader was used originally):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in another classloader
```

So how can I either find & use the appropriate class loader, or manage to find the library without re-loading it, so I can look for a symbol specifically from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the API needed to do this was made [public in 19](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk19/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/foreign/SymbolLookup.java#L197)

Before that, the advice was to manually implement this by binding `dlopen`, `dlclose`, and `dlsym` (or the Windows equivalents) to load the library and look up symbols.

e.g. on my Windows machine:

```
public class Main {
    
    static final MethodHandle MH_LoadLibraryA;
    static final MethodHandle MH_FreeLibrary;
    static final MethodHandle MH_GetProcAddress;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Kernel32");
        SymbolLookup lookup = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
        CLinker linker = CLinker.systemCLinker();
        MH_LoadLibraryA = linker.downcallHandle(
            lookup.lookup("LoadLibraryA").orElseThrow(),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(ADDRESS, ADDRESS));
        MH_FreeLibrary = linker.downcallHandle(
            lookup.lookup("FreeLibrary").orElseThrow(),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(JAVA_INT, ADDRESS));
        MH_GetProcAddress = linker.downcallHandle(
            lookup.lookup("GetProcAddress").orElseThrow(),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(ADDRESS, ADDRESS, ADDRESS));
    }

    static MemoryAddress LoadLibraryA(String name) {
        try (ResourceScope scope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope()) {
            SegmentAllocator allocator = SegmentAllocator.nativeAllocator(scope);
            return (MemoryAddress) MH_LoadLibraryA.invokeExact((Addressable) allocator.allocateUtf8String(name));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    static boolean FreeLibrary(MemoryAddress handle) {
        try {
            return ((int) MH_FreeLibrary.invokeExact((Addressable) handle)) != 0;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    static MemoryAddress GetProcAddress(MemoryAddress handle, String name) {
        try (ResourceScope scope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope()) {
            SegmentAllocator allocator = SegmentAllocator.nativeAllocator(scope);
            return (MemoryAddress) MH_GetProcAddress.invokeExact((Addressable) handle, (Addressable) allocator.allocateUtf8String(name));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }
    
    static SymbolLookup libraryLookup(String libraryName, ResourceScope scope) {
        MemoryAddress handle = LoadLibraryA(libraryName);
        if (handle == MemoryAddress.NULL) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find library: " + libraryName);
        }
        scope.addCloseAction(() -> FreeLibrary(handle));
        return name -> {
            var addr = GetProcAddress(handle, name);
            return addr == MemoryAddress.NULL ?
                Optional.empty() : Optional.of(NativeSymbol.ofAddress(name, addr, scope));
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        try (ResourceScope scope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope()) {
            SymbolLookup lookup = libraryLookup("gg", scope);
            MethodHandle handle = CLinker.systemCLinker().downcallHandle(
                lookup.lookup("get_gg").orElseThrow(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(JAVA_INT));
            int x = (int) handle.invoke();
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```